# Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am trying to run the same code(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export) Export class by adding the all the required jars to the class path from java command line path( ./java -cp ".:/npachava/*" Export test /test) ,I am getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot initialize Cluster. Please check your configuration for mapreduce.framework.name and the correspond server addresses.
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.initialize(Cluster.java:120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1260)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$9.run(Job.java:1256)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at Export.main(Export.java:194)
```

But running from the command prompt fromthe hbase bin directory( ./hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export test /TestTableData) works perfectly fine.

I have tried to set the config to yarn/local but both didnt worked

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn"); also with "local"
```

anyone please help

I am running with hbase 0.94.17 version on my linux.

Comment: *and the correspond server addresses.* what did you configure for that?

Comment: I didnt configure any and in the hbase-site.xml confiugured every server as local host i.e. 127.0.0.1,is their anything I need to set configuration pragmatically ?

Answer (score 15):

add [hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient) (select hadoop version before downloading).

Comment: please explain your answer a little bit more

Comment: added this jar in class path ,then it worked fine for me

Comment: @Mentya , Could you please explain how to add the jar file into the classspath?

Comment: @Mentya , Iam not using maven. What is the other way to add the jar file to the classpath

Comment: Why should it solve the problem? What is dependent form the joblcient?

Answer (score 9):

Solved as @mentya says.

If you are using Maven, You can add it to your **pom.xml** too.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the reason of such approach? Why this should solve the problem?